# adding array of picturebox into panel c#

Tags: c#, arrays, picturebox

```
private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox[] imgArray;   
PBflowLayoutPanel.Size = new Size(dww, dwh);
imgArray = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox[nTiles];    

for (int i = 0; i < nTiles; i++)
{
    imgArray[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
    imgArray[i].Margin = new Padding(0);
    imgArray[i].Size = new Size(dtw, dth);
    PBflowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(imgArray[i]);
    imgArray[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
}
```

I'm trying to create an array of picturebox to use them in panel. This code of mine does not shows any picture box in panel. What is that I'm missing?

Comment: Another thing you could try would be to add a `GridView` or something, and set it's `ItemsSource` to your `imgArray`.

Comment: This code does not shows any picture box in panel, probably, because picture boxes doesn't have images; add images or at least try `imgArray[i].BorderStyle=BorderStyle.FixedSingle;` to see, if they are being added

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine.

Add this line:

`imgArray[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;`

And you will see picture boxes.